# What does View.isActivated() do?

Tags: android, view

I came across the `View.isActivated()` method recently and am not sure what it does. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isActivated%28%29) says:

> public boolean isActivated ()
>
> Indicates the activation state of this view.
>
> Returns true if the view is activated, false otherwise

What does the state of a view mean? And when would a View be activated vs not activated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Activation is a longer-term state that the user can move views in and
>   out of. For example, in a list view with single or multiple selection
>   enabled, the views in the current selection set are activated. (Um,
>   yeah, we are deeply sorry about the terminology here.) The activated
>   state is propagated down to children of the view it is set on.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated(boolean)